# First Drupal Module - converting PHP script to Drupal 7 Module

Tags: php, xml, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to convert a much used PHP script that has served me well as a block for a while but now I am trying to convert it into a module for ease of use, and for the challenge. It puts a block into the list but not any content into the block. As I am more of a HTML5 / CSS3 geek this PHP is a little new to me. Could anyone help mentor me here? Many thanks

```
<code>
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * A block module that displays a local weather forcast for Reading Berks UK.
 */

function moduleone_help($path, $arg) {
  switch ($path) {
    case "admin/help#moduleone":
      return '<p>' . t("Displays the weather for a user defined region defined by <a href='#'>LINK</a>") . '</p>';
      break;
  }
} 

/**
 * Implement hook_block_info().
 */
function moduleone_block_info() {
  $blocks['moduleone'] = array(
    // The name that will appear in the block list.
    'info' => t('Module One Weather'),
    // Default setting.
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}
/**
 * Custom content function.
 *
 * Get weather report from Yahoo
 * Output var is $output.
 *
 * @return
 *   A result set of the targeted posts.
 */
function moduleone_weather(){
    $zipcode = 'UKXX0117';
        $result = file_get_contents('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=' . $zipcode . '&u=f');
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

//echo htmlspecialchars($result, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('yweather', 'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0');
    $location = $xml->channel->xpath('yweather:location');

        if(!empty($location)){
            foreach($xml->channel->item as $item){
                $current = $item->xpath('yweather:condition');
                $forecast = $item->xpath('yweather:forecast');
                $current = $current[0];
                $output = <<<END
                <h1 style="margin-bottom: 0">Weather for {$location[0]['city']}, {$location[0]['region']}</h1>
                <small>{$current['date']}</small>
                <h2>Current Conditions</h2>
                <p>
                    <span style="font-size:72px; font-weight:bold;">{$current['temp']}&deg;F</span>
                    <br/>
                    <img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/{$current['code']}.gif" style="vertical-align: middle;"/>&nbsp;
                    {$current['text']}
                </p>
                <h2>Forecast</h2>
                    {$forecast[0]['day']} - {$forecast[0]['text']}. High: {$forecast[0]['high']} Low: {$forecast[0]['low']}
                    <br/>
                    {$forecast[1]['day']} - {$forecast[1]['text']}. High: {$forecast[1]['high']} Low: {$forecast[1]['low']}
                    <br/>
                    {$forecast[2]['day']} - {$forecast[2]['text']}. High: {$forecast[2]['high']} Low: {$forecast[2]['low']}
                    </p>
END;
    }

}else{
    $output = 'No results found, please try a different zip code.';
}

function moduleone_block_view($delta = '') {
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'moduleone':
      $block['subject'] = t('Weather Conditions');
      if (user_access('access content')) {
   }

        if (empty($output)) {
          $block['content'] = t('No forcast available.');
        }
        else {
          $block['content'] = theme('item_list', array(
            'items' => $output));
        }
      }
    return $block;
  }
}</code>
```

Comment: }else{
    $output = 'No results found, please try a different zip code.';
}

function moduleone_block_view($delta = '') {
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'moduleone':
      $block['subject'] = t('Weather Conditions');
      if (user_access('access content')) {
   }
/**
        if (empty($output)) {
          $block['content'] = t('No forcast available.');
        }
        else {
          $block['content'] = theme('item_list', array(
            'items' => $output));
        }
      }
    return $block;
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Drupal works via a system of hooks which you override, so rightly you've overridden hook_help, hook_block_info and hook_block_view but there is no hook_weather (well, at least not in core Drupal although a contributed module may provide one) so at the moment moduleone_weather() is never called.

You could fix this by placing $output = moduleone_weather(); before you check whether $output is empty or not in your hook_block_view function.